# Как работать с toggle?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении класса `active` одному элементу, этот класс убирался из другого(если он имеется). Так как нельзя, чтобы у двух блоков был класс `active`.
Необходимо, чтобы при клике на один блок, из другого блока убирался класс.
Как это можно сделать?
Вот пример:

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
for(var i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
  block[i].onclick = function () {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.block{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = block.length; i < max; i += 1) {
      block[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.box{
  width:320px;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Второй вариант:

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
  block[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector('.active');
    if (active) active.classList.remove('active');

    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width:320px;
}
.block {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Я хотел бы добавить что такое вполне достижимо без js, в сниппете ниже он для того чтобы не копи-пастить дивы.

Все что необходимо - атрибут `tabindex` и селектор `:focus`

```js
for (var i=0; i<100; i++)
  document.write('<div class="block" tabindex="1"></div>')
```

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: white;
}

.block:focus {
  transition: 0.3s;
  outline: none;
  transform:scale(1.2);
  border-radius:17px;
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение... Никогда не думал о  `focus-E`  в такой реализации....

Comment: @Air `:focus` вообще очень удобная штука, я уже писал ответы подобного характера, но сейчас наверное уже не найду

Comment: `Кто ищет,  тот всегда найдет...`  -- это просто мысли в слух...)))